# clang -cc1 and system includes

Tags: c++, clang, include-path, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following file `foo.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>

struct MyClass
{
  std::vector<int> v;
};
```

It can be successfully compiled with clang (I'm using clang 3.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 32bit):

```
clang++ -c foo.cpp
```

Now I want to print AST:

```
clang++ -cc1 -ast-print foo.cpp
```

and I've got the following error

```
foo.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
#include <vector>
         ^
struct MyClass {
};
1 error generated.
```

It looks like `clang++ -cc1` doesn't know about system include files etc.
I'm wondering how to set up includes for `clang++ -cc1`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [Frequently Asked Question](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html)

Answer (score 9):

You need to set up the right include paths.
on my system I added

```
-I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 -I/usr/include/c++/4.8
```

to the compiler flags. The first one was so that it could find
bits/c++config.h
Of course the 4.8 is due to the fact I am using a compiler compatible with g++-4.8

I also added

```
-std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++
```

as compiler options.
Hope this helps

Comment: Also try changing "-stdlib=libstdc++" to "-lstdc++", i.e. "clang -x c++  -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -Wall input.cpp -o output"

Answer (score 4):

@john is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18506724/2877364).  For posterity, the relevant portions of the [FAQ](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/FAQ.html) are (with names tweaked to match the question) :

> `clang -cc1` is the frontend, `clang` is the driver. The driver invokes the frontend with options appropriate for your system. To see these options, run:
>
> ```
> $ clang++ -### -c foo.cpp
> ```
>
> Some clang command line options are driver-only options, some are frontend-only options. Frontend-only options are intended to be used only by clang developers. Users should not run `clang -cc1` directly, because `-cc1` options are not guaranteed to be stable.
>
> If you want to use a frontend-only option (“a `-cc1` option”), for example `-ast-dump`, then you need to take the `clang -cc1` line generated by the driver and add the option you need. Alternatively, you can run `clang -Xclang <option> ...` to force the driver [to] pass `<option>` to `clang -cc1`.

I did the latter (`-Xclang`) for emitting precompiled headers:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -x c++-header foo.hpp -Xclang -emit-pch -o foo.hpp.pch <other options>
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

Without the `-Xclang`, `clang++` ignored the `-emit-pch`.  When I tried `-cc1`, I had the same problem as the OP — `clang++` accepted `-emit-pch` but didn't have the other options the driver normally provides.